# how to implement parallel computing using SPMD command in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Please anyone suggest me simple programming code using **SPMD command in MATLAB** by which i can easily see the timing difference between sequential code and parallel code using SPMD command.
I have tried so many code using SPMD command but always found that parallel code using SPMD command in MATLAB is taking more time than the sequential code..
I have core i3 processor, 2 GB RAM, 320 GB Hard Disc and MATLAB R2011a.

Comment: It takes me roughly 20 seconds to open and then close the matlabpool, i.e. without executing any code. Thus, to take advantage of the parallel processing speedup your routines should at least run for minutes.

Answer (score 5):

If you have only a single machine to run your SPMD blocks, you have to work extra-hard to see speedup. This is because many operations in MATLAB are intrinsically multithreaded. This multithreading is always going to be more efficient than sending data to other MATLAB processes (the workers) for computation. You might see speedup using SPMD on a single machine if MATLAB itself cannot multithread the operation.

Comment: Thanks Edric,

So Parallel computing toolbox is not beneficial for Single Machine easily..

Comment: It certainly can be, but it doesn't always help. Of course, you also get GPU support with Parallel Computing Toolbox. Also, the things that SPMD is really good at (linear algebra) trend to be the things that are multi threaded in MATLAB. PARFOR is usually easier to use.